# I am facing Loop issue in DOM Manipulation, Can anyone look at it please?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to make rainbow text but I am unable to loop over, can anyone help?

This is the HTML

````
<body>
    <h1>
        <span>R</span>
        <span>A</span>
        <span>I</span>
        <span>N</span>
        <span>B</span>
        <span>O</span>
        <span>W</span>
    </h1>
</body>```
````

And this is the javascript

```
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']
```

I want to loop colors over the span using `document.querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're hoping to accomplish here. I *think* you want to color the individual letters with the elements in your colors array sequentially.

You can do that in several different ways. One of the more straightforward solutions would be to execute a callback function on an (array-like) nodelist using the `forEach` method.

Something like this...

1. Gather your spans into a nodelist (using `querySelectorAll`)
2. Iterate over the members of that nodelist (passing in the member variable and the index property)
3. Assign an inline style (the color corresponding to the index in the colors array) in your callback function.

Or, you could add a class instead and probably others things as well.

Good luck.

```js
const letters = document.querySelectorAll('.letters span');
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];

letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
  letter.style.color = colors[index]
})
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="letters">
    <span>R</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>N</span>
    <span>B</span>
    <span>O</span>
    <span>W</span>
  </h1>
</body>
```